# Define a dynamic output inside a variable?

Tags: javascript

I hope the title is not wrongfully put or misleading. What I want to do, in order to cut down unnecessary repetition of code, is something like this:

```
const predefinedOutput = "for(let i = 0; i < movie.length; i++) {
    output += `<div class="card">
    <div class="overlay">
    <div class="movie">
        <h2>${movie[i].title}</h2>
            <p><strong>Rating:</strong> ${movie[i].vote_average}</p>
            <p><strong>Release date:</strong> ${movie[i].release_date}</p>
            <a onclick="movieSelected('${movie[i].id}')" href="#">Details</a>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card_img">
        <img src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300/${movie[i].poster_path}" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='../images/imageNotFound.png';">
    </div>
    </div>`;
};
```

How can I, if its doable at all, to sort of pre-define an output that includes a forloop, that will be then used in an API call, so I don't make duplicates of the code above for different searches (page change, genre change etc.)?

Comment: It’s not clear to me why you don’t just use function. Why does this need to be a string?

Comment: Well, heres a link to hastebin to see how I have it right now. Because I am first checking if the movie belongs to the watchlist or favorites list, I need to do if / else statement in here, and that way it jumpst from about 250 lines to at least double. https://hastebin.com/iyeviwepan.coffeescript As you can see, from line 28 to line 68, its pretty huge ammount of unnecessary code repetition if I need to make this for a page change request for example, below this. And I'm not sure how I'd use a function to solve this..

Comment: You are probably better off using an html template framework such as AngularJS. It's specifically made to handle these kinds of scenarios so you don't have to code it yourself. In particular, look into [ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

Comment: @Petar Please keep in mind that, generally, if you are storing code as a string you are doing something wrong. There is almost always a better, safer, faster, more correct way. If you find yourself thinking the solution is to use a string to store code you should reconsider what your problem actually is.

Comment: "*How can I sort of pre-define [something] that includes a forloop so I don't make duplicates of the code*" - put it in a **`function`** that you can call as often as you want

Comment: @Bergi thanks, didn't knew if its possible to do something like that for this sort of "issue" :D

Answer (score 0):

Try the following example. Don't know what movies is so had to make something of it. In this example it should be an array. You could also use `.map()` but then the `movies` should be an object. `map` and `forEach` do the same as a `for` loop

```
<script>
movies.forEach( movie => {
    output += `<div class="card">
                    <div class="overlay">
                        <div class="movie">
                            <h2>${movie.title}</h2>
                                <p><strong>Rating:</strong> ${movie.vote_average}</p>
                                <p><strong>Release date:</strong> ${movie.release_date}</p>
                                <a onclick="movieSelected('${movie.id}')" href="#">Details</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card_img">
                        <img src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300/${movie.poster_path}" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='../images/imageNotFound.png';">
                    </div>
                </div>`;
});
```